# Calculate ProgressBar size according to database size

Tags: android, database, progress-bar, splash-screen

In my splash screen I am showing a progress bar while downloading data from remote server.
I am downloading 3 tables of data from remote database.
each table can be in different size.
each table downloading process invoked by different function.
I want to calculate and update the progress bar while downloading the data.

for example:
Table 1 - 100 lines
Table 2 - 30 lines
Table 3 - 230 lines

Downloading data invoked from method doInBckground:

```
    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(String... params) {
        downloadTable1();
        downloadTable2();
        downloadTable3();
    }
```

I thought of two options for achieving this:
1)
get size of data from all 3 tables, then before starting to download calculating the percentage of each line of downloaded data on the progress bar.
For the example above, 100+30+230=360 lines to download.
each line that will be download will progress the progress bar in 0.27%

2)
Or set from advanced to proportion of each table, and then set the amount of progress accordingly. for example if i assume that table 3 will always be the biggest, table 2 is the smallest and table 1 in the middle.
so I can fix their impact on the progress bar by:
Table 1 30%
Table 2 20%
Table 3 50%
Then in each method that download the table to make progress only for that amount.

My question is, what is the common way to achieve this goal of making accurate progress bar that will progress correctly while downloading data from 3 different database tables that can vary in their size.

example for one of the methods that download the data:

```
//Download Table1 data and save it in SQLite MAINCAT Table
private void downloadTable1() {
    //-1 Code in PHP file to get Table1
    String respond = getHttpRespond(-1);                      //The String respond got from HTTP request
    DB_SQLiteManager db = new DB_SQLiteManager(context);    //Prepare SQLite database object for future downloaded data

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(respond);                            //the result in JSON
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts");                     //result in Array of JSON

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            //Update progressbar value
            totalProgressBarValue = totalProgressBarValue+i;
            publishProgress(totalProgressBarValue);

            JSONObject curr = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);                           //Get current line

            String strID = curr.optJSONObject("post").optString("id");              //Get current string ID
            String strName = curr.optJSONObject("post").optString("name");          //Get current string et_Name
            String imageLink = curr.optJSONObject("post").optString("imagelink");
            String strPosition = curr.optJSONObject("post").optString("position");

            //Insert row of data to SQLite MAINCAT table
            db.addDataLineToTableMAINCAT(Integer.parseInt(strID), strName, imageLink, Integer.parseInt(strPosition));
            System.out.println("ADDEDD: " + strID + strName + imageLink + strPosition);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please show the downloadTable methods

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a "common way" to achieve this.  Your first suggestion seems more reasonable/accurate if you can easily find the size of the tables.

Comment: In order to find their sizes i have to download them first? then the progress bar cant be filled while downloading...

Comment: Yes that's true, but if the data is something you control you could retrieve just the sizes of the tables before you start the download of the mass of data.

Comment: Do you mean maybe to add another table in the sql server that will hold one value only - the size of all the other data to download?

Comment: Yeah something like that, that you could access fast. If you don't have some knowledge of the table size you can't be accurate with your progress updates.